# Drawing.Image.RotateFlip doesn't seem to work on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, image

I have some fairly simple code getting the rotation from the EXIF data of an image and then calling Image.RotateFlip to rotate it:

```
            using Stream targetStream = sourceFile.Open();
        const int dimensions = 120;
        Image image = Image.FromStream(targetStream, false, false);

        // An image may have EXIF (Exchangeable Image File Format) tags set on it, including an orientation property which indicates the orientation of the
        // camera relative to the captured image. The Id of this property is 0x0112 he hex equivalent of 274. 
        if (Array.IndexOf(image.PropertyIdList, 274) > -1)
        {
           var orientation = (int)image.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0];
           switch (orientation)
           {
              //The rotations below are to get the image back to the horizontal (normal) positions.
              default:
              case 1:
                 // Horizontal (normal). No rotation required.
                 // The start of the image will be orientated in the top left corner.
                 break;
              case 2:
                 // Mirrored horizontally.
                 // The start of the image will be orientated in the top right corner.  
                 image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
                 break;
              case 3:
                 // Rotated 180 degrees.
                 // The start of the image will be orientated in the bottom right corner.
                 image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                 break;
              case 4:
                 // Mirrored vertically.
                 // The start of the image will be orientated in the bottom left corner.
                 image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                 break;
              case 5:
                 // Mirrored horizontally and rotated 90 clockwise.
                 // The start of the image will be orientated in the top left corner.
                 image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
                 break;
              case 6:
                 // Rotated 90 degrees clockwise.
                 // The start of the image will be orientated in the top right corner.
                 image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                 break;
              case 7:
                 // Mirrored horizontally and rotated 270 degrees clockwise.
                 // The start of the image will be orientated in the bottom right corner.
                 image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX);
                 break;
              case 8:
                 // Rotated 270 degrees clockwise.
                 // The start of the image will be orientated in the bottom left corner.
                 image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                 break;
           }
        }

        float ratio = GetImageRatio(image.Height, image.Width);
        int newDimensions = (int)(ratio * dimensions);
        Image thumbnail = image.Height > image.Width
           ? image.GetThumbnailImage(newDimensions, dimensions, () => false, IntPtr.Zero)
           : image.GetThumbnailImage(dimensions, newDimensions, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);

        using (Stream saveStream = CreateFile(newThumbnailFile, CreateFileOption.OverwriteExisting))
        {
           thumbnail.Save(saveStream, GetImageFormat(file));
        }
        image.Dispose();
     }
```

The resultant thumbnail image is in the correct orientation when run on a windows environment, but under a Linux environment, the image is simply not rotated. The value is read correctly and the RotateFlip method called, but it doesn't appear to actually update the image. Has anyone else run  into this bug?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `RotateFlip`, which is not working on Linux? You didn't tell what the targeted framework is (.NET Core/.NET 5+ or .NET Framework powered by Mono) but I have a WinForms [project](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools#compatibility) that uses `RotateFlip` even on Linux/Mono and it works for sure. I suspect that it's the `GetPropertyItem`, which is not fully supported by the underlying libgdiplus component, which is used by the native `System.Drawing` calls on Linux.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Its a .NET core application. I will look into GetPropertyItem alternatives and give those a try.